# React native dynamic themes through json data

Tags: css, ajax, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

In react native how can i override my custom style over dynamic style in which font-size and background colour returning from the server in JSON data?
And i want to set that JSON data theme in my style themes?can you please send me the syntax of that type of style which accept JSON data like font size or colour and create dynamic theme?

Answer (score 0):

you can always customise your style in a component, suppose you have a component:

```
const MyComponent = ({size, color}) => <Text style={{color: color, fontSize:size}}>Hello</Text>;
```

in your parent component, you can retrieve your theme data from the sever side like

```
const themeJson = retrieveTheme()  // some API call
```

Suppose you have `color` and `size` in ur retrieved JSON data.
you can always pass the theme color and font size in to `MyComponent` as

```
<MyComponent color={themeJson.color} fontSize={themeJson.size} />
```

then, the text size and color will be changed according to the theme JSON data.

In react native, style definition is different from react, it uses `StyleSheet` to create the style instance, we can not change it like what we do in React project (which is a JSON Object), if you wanna customise it when rendering it, you can always put the customise styling in the array like

```
const styles= StyleSheet.create({
   existStyle={
     color: "red",
     fontSize: 15
   }
});

const MyComponent = ({size, color}) => 
<Text style={[styles.existStyle, {color: color, fontSize: size}] style={{color: color, fontSize:size}}>Hello</Text>;
```

It will overwrite the existing style you defined at the top. Hopefully, it will help.